# Apache Logging PHP Requests

Tags: apache, logging

i want log in my accesslog the full urls not just this.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2011:20:19:48 +0200] "GET /test/index1.php HTTP/1.1" 200 31333 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0"
```

i want log for example:

/test/index.php?page=10 or I use also mod rewrite than it would be /test/Page/100

is this possible?

On my server is running Apache / PHP 5

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html) directive to specify the exact format that you want.  The parameter for the query string is `%q`